# SharePoint 2007 : old items unable to search

Tags: search, crawling, pages

I having a problem on SharePoint 2007 search in OS 32bit.

Where one of the subsite contains more than 600 pages, but the incremental crawl only able to crawl some of the pages (70++) only, crawl log do not record any warning or error.

Due to the application is already in production environment, I not able to perform full crawl because worried the impact to the application.

I was suspected all the item was too old, which is not successfully crawl during the last full crawl. However, all the newly created items was able to crawl from the incremental crawl.

What is the action I can investigate on? please help.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How frequently you run full crawl?

Answer (score 1):

You should periodically perform full crawls especially when you have aspx pages. Check out this article for information on when incremental crawls will not work : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/full-and-incremental-crawls-in-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-search.aspx